# I cannot access a variable outside a class

Tags: c#

I'm making a blackjack project..

I've firstly created the `Hit` class for the `Hit` Button.

So on the form, when I click it, it will retrieve a value from the switch case scenario that has randomized a number/value within the hit class.

I've tried making a variable just under the Class hit to = stRefID within the `GenerateID` method but this failed as well; everything is public, so I'm baffled.

Thank you for your time & assisting me with this, as it's my first time actually posting here, but I use this place all the time.

**Hit.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Blackjack
{
public class Hit
{
    public static string GenerateID(int MinSize, int MaxSize)
    {

        string stRefID = "";

        Random random = new Random();

            int iChosenMaxSize = random.Next(0, 11);

            int two = 2;
            int three = 3;
            int four = 4;
            int five = 5;
            int six = 6;
            int seven = 7;
            int eight = 8;
            int nine = 9;
            int ten = 10;
            int jack = 10;
            int queen = 10;
            int king = 10;
            int ace = 11;


         for (int x = 1; x <= iChosenMaxSize; x++)
        {
            int iCharType = random.Next(0, 12);
            switch (iCharType)
            {
                    case 0:
                        stRefID += two;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        stRefID += three;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        stRefID += four;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        stRefID += five;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        stRefID += six;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        stRefID += seven;
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        stRefID += eight;
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        stRefID += nine;
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        stRefID += ten;
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        stRefID += ace;
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        stRefID += jack;
                        break;
                    case 11:
                        stRefID += queen;
                        break;
                    case 12:
                        stRefID += king;
                        break;

                }
             } return stRefID; 

        }
    }
}
```

And where I would like to retrieve and set the text box to the value retrieved:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Blackjack
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{


        private void hit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         this.test.Text = Hit.stRefID;

    }
```

I've attempted making the button public as well but this failed...

test text box for output:

```
private void test_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Kind regards,
Mike.

Revised Code:

```
namespace Blackjack
{
public class Hit
{

    public static string GenerateID(string stRefID)

    {

        Random random = new Random();

            int iChosenMaxSize = random.Next(0, 11);

            int two = 2;
            int three = 3;
            int four = 4;
            int five = 5;
            int six = 6;
            int seven = 7;
            int eight = 8;
            int nine = 9;
            int ten = 10;
            int jack = 10;
            int queen = 10;
            int king = 10;
            int ace = 11;


         for (int x = 1; x <= iChosenMaxSize; x++)
        {
            int iCharType = random.Next(0, 12);
            switch (iCharType)
            {
                    case 0:
                        stRefID += two;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        stRefID += three;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        stRefID += four;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        stRefID += five;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        stRefID += six;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        stRefID += seven;
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        stRefID += eight;
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        stRefID += nine;
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        stRefID += ten;
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        stRefID += ace;
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        stRefID += jack;
                        break;
                    case 11:
                        stRefID += queen;
                        break;
                    case 12:
                        stRefID += king;
                        break;

                }
          } return stRefID; 

        }

}
}
```

I made the generateID method with stRefID because the return should go back to it - whereby I can call the value from the button? the public static string declaration works but only if I have a defaul value...

Comment: @Mike: Does your code compile. I guess `Hit.stRefID` should be throwing a compilation error.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your response here, yes it's: this.test.Text = Hit.GenerateID(stRefID);      and it says:  Error 1 The name 'stRefID' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I can access, the variable - but the method isn't setting it. so I'm trying to figure out what is wrong, I'll edit my first post with the revised code now

Comment: If I leave it as this.test.Text = Hit.GenerateID(); then it says No overload for method "GenerateID" takes '0' arguments.

Comment: `string stRefID = "someVal";  this.test.Text = Hit.GenerateID(stRefID);` You should declare `stRefID` first and then pass it..

Comment: Sure but I need to retrieve the stRefID from hit.cs within generateID as a return value from the switch case, if I set a random value - it just passes the random value =/

Comment: You're amazing! I made it             string stRefID = "";

Comment: Thank you so much for your help - I wish I could vote you up right now ):

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I understood completely.

But I could see that `stRefID` is a variable `local` to `GenerateID` function.

If you need to access it as `Hit.stRefID` then `stRefID` should be a static class member

Try adding `stRefID` as [`static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691162%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) global `Class` variable.

```
public class Hit
{
    public static string stRefID = "";

    public static string GenerateID(int MinSize, int MaxSize)
    {
       //Your logic
    }
```

Comment: It's a variable scope issue. If he makes stRefID static, it is possible he will access it before it is assigned a useful value.  On top of that, the value will never change unless he calls `GenerateID` which currently returns the value of stRefID like he is looking for.

Comment: @TheGreatCO: Ya I could see the scope issue. But I wasn't sure why he was trying to make the `button public`.

Comment: Yep I pretty much though the same ... Then again not sure why `GenerateID` needs to be static either.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov: Since we don't see the `GenerateID` function call its hard to make a guess..

Comment: @jacobaloysious Exactly !:)

Comment: Excellent after adding  public static string stRefID = "";  I think my switch case logic is flawed though, as it's either not working or setting stRefID... but the value does get sent from stRefID... thanks for the help people.   The GenerateID function is for the switch case to run?

Comment: @user2400333 you aren't setting the static stRefID.  Not only that, your original code worked fine, you simply weren't using it right. You  need to call `GenerateID` and use the value returned from it.  You do NOT need a static class member.  This is bad on many levels of coding.

Comment: namespace Blackjack
{
    public class Hit
    {
      
        public static string GenerateID(string stRefID)

Comment: So now it should return stRefID to the method - whereby I should be able to call it from the onClick event?

Comment: private void hit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.test.Text = Hit.GenerateID(stRefID);

        }

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access a variable defined inside a method. stRefID's scope is strictly inside GenerateID.  Based on your class, if you want to access the value of stRefID, you need to call `Hit.GenerateID`, this will return the value of stRefID.  Scope of variables is very important in C# (as with all programming languages).  I suggest you take a look at [C# Variable Scope](http://www.codecandle.com/Articles/191/Csharp/Variables/Variable-scope/codedetail.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

what u have done is declared the `stRefID` variable inside the scope of the method `GenerateID` this is not gonna work so what u can do is put that variable within the scope of the class and then u can use it like this.

```
namespace Blackjack
   {
    public class Hit
      {
       string stRefID = "";

       public static string GenerateID(int MinSize, int MaxSize)
        {
        Random random = new Random();

        int iChosenMaxSize = random.Next(0, 11);

        int two = 2;
        int three = 3;
        int four = 4;
        int five = 5;
        int six = 6;
        int seven = 7;
        int eight = 8;
        int nine = 9;
        int ten = 10;
        int jack = 10;
        int queen = 10;
        int king = 10;
        int ace = 11;


     for (int x = 1; x <= iChosenMaxSize; x++)
    {
        int iCharType = random.Next(0, 12);
        switch (iCharType)
        {
                case 0:
                    stRefID += two;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    stRefID += three;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    stRefID += four;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    stRefID += five;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    stRefID += six;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    stRefID += seven;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    stRefID += eight;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    stRefID += nine;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    stRefID += ten;
                    break;
                case 9:
                    stRefID += ace;
                    break;
                case 10:
                    stRefID += jack;
                    break;
                case 11:
                    stRefID += queen;
                    break;
                case 12:
                    stRefID += king;
                    break;

            }
         } return stRefID; 

    }
```

this should work fine i guess